# What is happening in this fuction?

Tags: c++, vector, return, cout

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int print_vector(vector<int> &data) {
    int size = data.size();
    cout<< "size " << size << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        if(data[i] == 3) {
            return i;
        }
        cout<< data[i] << endl;
    }
    cout<< "Hello!" << endl;
    return data.size() - 1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> data = {1,2,3,4,5};
    
    cout<<  print_vector(data) << endl;
}
```

When I run my code, once it reaches my `if` statement, it returns `i` and then returns `data.size()` which is only 2, and if I do `data.size() -1` it is still 2.

Why does this happen? Can anybody help?

Comment: it's returning the index that contains the value 3. That's what `if(data[i]==3) return i;` does. what's the mystery?

Comment: A function can't return twice. Once it has returned, control is back to the caller.

Comment: It prints the elements till it reaches the second index which is 3, then returns the index to the caller which is the main function. This return value is then printed in main.

Comment: No surprises here, did you maybe confuse "returning a value" with "printing a value"? Carefully trace the code (in a debugger preferably) to see why it prints what it prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we trace the flow of control in your program it should become obvious what's happening:

1. From `main` we call `print_vector(data)`
2. The first output is `size 5` from `cout<< "size " << size << endl;`
3. We enter the `for`-loop:

   1. First iteration (`i == 0`, `data[i] == 1`)

      - `if(data[i] == 3)` evaluates to `false`
      - We get the output `1` from `cout<< data[i] << endl;`
   2. Second iteration (`i == 1`, `data[i] == 2`)

      - `if(data[i] == 3)` evaluates to `false`
      - We get the output `2` from `cout<< data[i] << endl;`
   3. Third iteration (`i == 2`, `data[i] == 3`)

      - `if(data[i] == 3)` evaluates to `true`
      - We break the loop by returning `i` (which is `2`)
4. The value returned from `print_vector` is printed in `cout<<  print_vector(data) << endl;`

So the output you get is

```
size 5
1
2
2
```

---

The function doesn't return twice (that's just not possible), nor does the size of the vector magically decrease. In fact, you only print the size once, so there is no reason to expect any of those numbers (except the first) the be related to the vectors size.